# how to click if table have multiple class, this is gmail searching part i have attached screenshot please check

Tags: python, selenium, automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2oMr.png)

how to click if a table has multiple classes, this is Gmail searching part I have attached screenshot please check

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can greatly improve your chances of getting an answer if you write more specific questions with a clear end goal. And consider giving your question a more detailed description than simply repeating the your question title . It can also help if you include keywords in your title. Like "**Click** on an **element with non unique class** in **Selenium**"

Comment: i am searching email in gmail inbox and want to read first email from the search result, everything is working fine but unable to read first email from the search result please refer screenshot, i am share the code what i had done   `driver.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/"+str(search))
myData = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='zA yO']")`
now myData have list of elements, i don't know how to click on that elements,
even i am not able open any email from the search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the code wherein I am able to click on the 1st item in the Gmail.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://mail.google.com")

time.sleep(2)
username = ""
password = ""

# Fill username
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@autocomplete="username"]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('VfPpkd-RLmnJb').click()
time.sleep(5)
# Fill password
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="password"]').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('VfPpkd-RLmnJb').click()

time.sleep(10)
# Find the search textbox and then search for 'geo' keyword
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@aria-label="Search mail"]').send_keys("geo")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@aria-label="Search mail"]').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(10)

# Click on the first gmail item.
gmail_1stitem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1])[2]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(gmail_1stitem).click(gmail_1stitem).perform()
```

Note - if it solve your problem, then please mark this as a answer.

Comment: not working, getting this error `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable` i have tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@class,'zA')]")[1].click()` also then getting this error `TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/zomato     you can replace **zomato** which your have already exist in you inbox

Comment: `emailitem = '(//tr[contains(@class,"zA")])[1]'`
`driver.find_element_by_xpath(emailitem).click()` - Try this.

Comment: getting the same error, `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable` is it working for you ?

Comment: @farhanAlam I have updated code in main thread, wherein I am able to click on the 1st item in the Gmail. Modify code to suit your need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use contains method to click on specific tr element.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr[contains(text(), 'Your text')]")))
element.click();
```

or

check if id is not dynamic and use below solution to click on first element from the table.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr[@id=':ls']")))
element.click();
```